# how to refer to the field of found document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using Mongoose in Node.js and I have a problem

I want to update a field in the document , for example, add a suffix for a filed

how do I refer  to the field of found document in update action?

I try to use this. to reference the found document's fields, but it doesn't work?

what should I do?

```
tcModel.findOneAndUpdate({}, {title: this.title + 'x'}).then((data) => {console.log(data)})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) in [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to do that:

```
tcModel.findOneAndUpdate({}, [{ $set: { title: { $concat: ["$title", "x"] } } }])...
```